# PDF reader in html?

Tags: php, html, pdf, embed

I have online ebook store. how can I create a pdf reader so that user can read 5-6 pages as demo or sample of my ebooks.Or is there any way to display 5-10 poages of my ebook.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iFrame or something along with Google Docs Viewer.

They have [url instructions](https://docs.google.com/viewer), pretty simple.

> Technical Documentation - Instructions for building your own URLs
> All viewer URLs should use the path http://docs.google.com/viewer . This path accepts two parameters:
> url : The URL of the document to view. This should be URL-encoded.
> embedded : If set to true , the viewer will use an embedded mode interface.
> For example, if you wanted to view the PDF at the URL http://labs.google.com/papers/bigtable-osdi06.pdf , you would use the URL: http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Flabs.google.com%2Fpapers%2Fbigtable-osdi06.pdf